# How to translate the text in Vega

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I would like when I use text in Vega it is internationalized.

for example :

```
legend: {
               ....
              labelExpr: "datum.value == 'TIME' ? i18next.t('LATE') : i18next.t('TIME')"
             }
```

in this example internationalization does not work.

Is there a solution to be able to translate easily in Vega ?

Comment: Can you add a sample or a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vega expressions cannot be arbitrary javascript; the functionality available is listed here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/

Translation is not among the available functionality. The best way to do this is probably to pre-populate a translated column in the dataset before passing it to the vega specification.

Comment: I fully agree that the translation must be processed in the dataset, but if I want to translate a key present for example in a tooltip expr as below :  tooltip: {
            expr: "{title: datum.qualification, 'amount': datum.sum_amount}",
          }, Is there no solution to translate the "amount" key

Comment: No, the `'amount'` key is part of the vega expression, so it can only use the subset of functionality documented at the link above. You could address this by preprocessing the data to add a new column with the translated key.